tlp not surviving a reboot
I have enabled tlp to enable charge_control_end_threshold = 80%.
However, this is not surviving a reboot. After a rebbot, I am getting:
sudo systemctl status tlp.service 
○ tlp.service - TLP system startup/shutdown
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tlp.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: https://linrunner.de/tlp
sudo tlp-stat -b
[sudo] password for rudra: 
--- TLP 1.6.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: asus
Supported features: charge threshold
Driver usage:
* natacpi (asus_wmi) = active (charge threshold)
Parameter value range:
* STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0/1: 0(off)..100(default)

+++ Battery Status: BAT0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = ASUSTeK
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = ASUS Battery
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =    104
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  75086 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  68032 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  52042 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =   2997 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Discharging

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold   =    100 [%]

Charge                                                      =   76.5 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   90.6 [%]

I have to restart the service manually again to get the things back:
sudo systemctl restart tlp.service 
sudo systemctl status tlp.service 
● tlp.service - TLP system startup/shutdown
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tlp.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2024-10-06 00:26:51 IST; 1s ago
 Invocation: c137b95091b2476c9c72f885dafe5bda
       Docs: https://linrunner.de/tlp
    Process: 5091 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/tlp init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 5091 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Mem peak: 7.6M
        CPU: 231ms

Oct 06 00:26:51 roddur systemd[1]: Starting tlp.service - TLP system startup/shutdown...
Oct 06 00:26:51 roddur tlp[5091]: Applying power save settings...done.
Oct 06 00:26:51 roddur tlp[5091]: Setting battery charge thresholds...done.
Oct 06 00:26:51 roddur systemd[1]: Finished tlp.service - TLP system startup/shutdown.

sudo tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.6.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: asus
Supported features: charge threshold
Driver usage:
* natacpi (asus_wmi) = active (charge threshold)
Parameter value range:
* STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0/1: 0(off)..100(default)

+++ Battery Status: BAT0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = ASUSTeK
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = ASUS Battery
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =    104
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  75086 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  68032 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  51675 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =   5834 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Discharging

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold   =     80 [%]

Charge                                                      =   76.0 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   90.6 [%]

In tlp-support, there is a similar report, but in that case, the asus battery was not detected: https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#faq-asus-threshold-not-set-on-boot
But, in this case, battery is detected, hence I am bit hesitant to unload asus-wsi module. Any help please?

which distribution are you using?
have you tried to add the asus_wsi mofule to the initramfs ?
